# Can I use WP's built in domain mapping with WP installed on a sub-domain?

Tags: subdomains, domain-mapping

I have WP MU installed on a subdomain, `my.example.com`.

When I use WP's built in domain mapping, I receive a 404 when I try to view a network site's home page, e.g: `www.example2.org`.

Can I use WP's built in domain mapping with WP installed on a sub-domain?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your problem, assuming you are using Apache web server, paste this into your `.htaccess` (the `.htaccess` inside the sub-domain (my) directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Once you have completed that, go to your DNS settings and set up a wildcard DNS entry for your domain. This basically says to Apache:

> "If someone comes to this (sub,) sub-domain, this is the IP for it.

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx A *.my.example.com

That should work fine. as it did for me.

---

**EDIT**: The OP has edited his question. This answer may or may not be a solution for the problem above, although this will fix majority of problems with wildcard sub-domain, WordPress Multisite installations.

Comment: Thx Josh. When I created this sub-domain, cPanel created a new folder @ /home/user/my.example.com, and I edited `.htaccess` in this directory with the above, but the issue remains.

Comment: In cPanel, go to the search box at the top right (in the newer versions) and search for `Advanced Zone Editor`. Here, create a new A record, as stated above (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` being your IP address). You can find you IP by looking at any of the other A records referring to `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks. There is already an entry `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx my.example.com` listed in Advanced Zone Editor.

Comment: The record must have an asterisk (*) symbol at the start. Copy the record example below but fill in your information: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx A *.my.example.com`. Notice the `*.` in front of `my.example.com`.

Comment: Apologies Josh. The A record for `*.my.example.com` already existed too.

Comment: The only thing I can say now is look at the following article on the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping.